# Flexbox align-content space between with flex column

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I want to take the read more button and push it to the bottom of this card. Is there an equivalent of `align-content:space-between` for `flex-col`? The top section, middle paragraph, and see more button are all in their own div wrapped inside the parent card div.

[image]

Comment: If you provide a [mcve] we might be able to help

Comment: it turns to be justify-content:space-between; mind that it goes with flex-direction

Comment: yes and I need it to be flex direction column

Comment: so use justify-content ..... should i repeat it goes with flex-direction ? If it doesn't work, then clarify your question with the code that shows your issue. screenshot are useless

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a combination of `justify-content: space-between` and `text-align: right` to the readmore button.

This results in:

```css
.card {
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.child-2 {
  text-align: right;
}

.child {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="child">
    <h1>Article Awesome</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione inventore, dolor dolorem vero, tenetur rerum tempora autem repudiandae deleniti rem sunt perferendis quasi dolore voluptatum fugit quisquam asperiores exercitationem. Exercitationem?
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="child child-2">Read More ...</div>
</div>
```

Note that you can set whatever height to the card and it will scale accordingly with the readmore button in the bottom.